# Regex para capturar infinitos grupos em uma URL separando-os pela barra

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer uma regex para capturar vários grupos como demonstrado na string abaixo:

/`Controller`/`Action`/`Param1`/`Param2`/`Param3`/...

Quero capturar "Controller", "Action", "Param1", "Param2", "Param3" e quantos mais tiverem separados por barra, cada um deve ser um match diferente para que possa utilizar `preg_match`do PHP e joga-las em um vetor.

Comment: Se você desse um substring até a primeira barra e depois fizesse um explode na barra? Serviria pra você?

Comment: Talvez.. mas procuro alguma solução que utilize apenas regex, se houver. Caso contrário terei de recorrer a outros métodos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Usando Expressão Regular

Embora a forma mais fácil de resolver seja com o [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php), se quiser usar expressão regular, aqui está:

```
$input = '/Controller/Action/Param1/Param2/Param3/';

preg_match_all("/\/?([^\/]+)/", $input, $output);

var_dump($output[1]);
```

Comment: Resolveu perfeitamente o problema utilizando Regex. Obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Precisa mesmo ser uma expressão regular? Que tal usar um [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)?

```
<?php
$str = 'Controller/Action/Param1/Param2/Param3';

$segments = explode('/', $str));
print_r($segments);
```

Esse exemplo irá retorar:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Controller 
    [1] => Action 
    [2] => Param1 
    [3] => Param2 
    [4] => Param3 
)
```

Veja [rodando](https://3v4l.org/ZEtVu).

Se ainda sim quiser utilizar uma regex, algo que pode te trazer o mesmo resultado é o [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php) (só que mais lento, se comparado com o `explode`)

```
$str = 'Controller/Action/Param1/Param2/Param3';

$segments = preg_split('/\//', $str);

print_r($segments);
```

Resultado:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Controller 
    [1] => Action 
    [2] => Param1 
    [3] => Param2 
    [4] => Param3 
)
```

Exemplo [rodando](https://3v4l.org/QpWQb).

Answer (score 4):

Não faz mesmo muito sentido usar regex pra isso, mas é possivel:

**Com regex**

```
$url = 'http://example.com/Controller/Action/Param1/Param2/Param3/...';

preg_match_all( '|/([^\/]+)|', $url, $matches );

var_dump( $matches );

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "/example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "/Controller"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "/Action"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "/Param1"
    [4]=>
    string(7) "/Param2"
    [5]=>
    string(7) "/Param3"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "/..."
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "example.com"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Controller"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "Action"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Param1"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Param2"
    [5]=>
    string(6) "Param3"
    [6]=>
    string(3) "..."
  }
}
```

**Sem regex**

```
$url = 'http://example.com/Controller/Action/Param1/Param2/Param3/...';
$split = explode( '/', $url );

var_dump( $split );

array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "http:"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
  [2]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "Controller"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Action"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Param1"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "Param2"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "Param3"
  [8]=>
  string(3) "..."
}
```

[**Veja funcionando**](https://eval.in/742085)

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho mais fácil e inteligente fazer tais parâmetros seguir uma lógica. Tornar o script inteligente e não tentar processar nada que não faz parte do sistema. ignorar ou estabelecer exceção de cara. Uma execução responsiva.
Tipo todos os teus controllers começarem com (Controller_) tudo que viver depois do (Controller_) é o que queremos pegar para saber qual controller e que classes chamaremos para essa URL.
Agora estabelecer que todos os Actions comecem com (Actions_) o que vem depois do (Action_) é o que pegamos para sabermos que action chamar em nossa classe e que classe levantar.
Por fim viria os parâmetros os quais estariam todos os parâmetros:
^(?:/)(?:[/]Action_([a-zA-Z]+))(?:/)+(?:[/])?

```
<?php

preg_match('/^(?:[\/](?:Controller_([a-zA-Z]+)))(?:[\/]Action_([a-zA-Z]+))(?:[\/]([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-\_]+))+(?:[\/])?/', $onde, $matches);

//Analisamos o controller se tiver um controller fazemos algo se
//não houver deixa tudo para lá sem controller não há trabalho a se fazer
if((isset($matches[1]) == true) and ($matches[1] != null) ){

//Já que tem controller na variável $matches[1] seguimos em frente

// Verificamos se há action, pois se não houver paramos
// por aqui e retorna a ação padrão do referido controller
if((isset($matches[2]) == true) and ($matches[2] != null) ){

// Se estamos aqui é por que tem um action a ser executado
// Então proseguimos

//Agora verificamos se tem parâmetros, se não houver essa parte não é executada
// e é executada somente a ação padrão para o referido action

if((isset($matches[3]) == true) and ($matches[3] != null) ){

// Como estamos aqui quer dizer que há parâmetros na variável $matches[3]
// Aplicamos um explode() nele

$pedacos = explode("/", $matches[3]);

//Analisamos cada parâmetros e tomamos decisões

}

}

}
?>
```

Essa expressão regular aceita:
/Controller_carrinho/Action_pagar/Param1/Param2/Param3/
/Controller_carrinho/Action_pagar/Param1/Param2/Param3
/Controller_carrinho/Action_pagar/Param1/
/Controller_carrinho/Action_pagar/Param1
/Controller_carrinho/Action_pagar
/Controller_carrinho/Action_pagar/
/Controller_carrinho/
/Controller_carrinho
O controller pode ser qualquer coisa desde que siga a lógica
Controller_comprar
Controller_vender
Controller_fazerpao
Controller_listarprodutos
Controller_fazercafe
Controller_comerarroz
As variáveis são:
$matches[1]
O nome do controler, só o que vem depois do underline
$matches[2]
O nome da ação, só o que vem depois do underline
$matches[3]
Todos os parâmetros desde que eles sejam letras com ou sem números e traços e underline.
Não importa se houver um traço no final, pois o mesmo é ignorado e tudo que não encaixe nisso também é ignorado.
Observação:
No caso da falta de alguma peça não há erros a referida variável terá o valor nulo.
Eu uso essa lógica para não ter que usar $_GET no meu site e não ficar analisando coisa que não faz parte e não segue a lógica do sistema.
Espero que ajude alguém!